# BOTON REGRESAR DEL NAVEGADOR

Tags: javascript, php, navegador-web, navbar

Espero que se encuentren bien
Tengo una duda y si alguien sabe, espero pueda ayudarme. Estoy desarrollando una pagina con HTML, PHP y Javascript
El problema que tengo es que a la hora que inicio sesion como usuario me lleva al home y aparece mi navbar, y hasta ahí todo bien. Pero a la hora que yo doy click en el boton de regresar del navegador, me lleva a mi formulario de inicio de sesion pero se queda cargada la navbar de la sesion (Son navbar diferentes, el de inicio de sesion (usuario y contraseña) y el navbar con iconos del home para navegar en la misma página). Alguien podria ayudarme con eso? O hay alguna forma de indicarle al boton del navegador alguna instrucción de redireccion o algo por el estilo?
Les agradecería su ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so], haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Muestra un [repro] de lo que tienes hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: En tu pantalla de sesión debería haber un control. Si ya está iniciada la sesión te redirecciona al home.